# Can I receive a small amount of money (<5$) without pan card on PayPal in India?

Tags: india, money-transfer, paypal

I am from India. I have a PayPal account with verified phone no. and email, but I don't have pan card / debit / credit card. So if someone sends money , can I receive that money without them? I don't want to withdraw but whatever the money I have received should be in my PayPal account. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, because of regulations Paypal is different in India to most countries and you cannot actually spend paypal balance. You will need to verify your PAN number and connect a bank account, although this should be very quick

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) . But are you sure? PayPal and Reserve Bank of India are very strict on this .

Comment: After some more research I was incorrect, it is different in India to most other countries. My apologies I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

very simple.

RBI has stopped connecting Indian Bank's to Paypal, for deposit or withdrawal. You need to use a third party website (Online wallet etc) to send whatever money you have in the Paypal account.

Connect your Bank account with the third party website, and withdraw the money